# Ensuring Security with Firestore Rules for Authenticated User Document Writes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am currently operating a React application hosted on Firebase Hosting and using Firebase Authentication for managing user authentication.

I have crafted the following firestore.rules to ensure that only the authenticated user themselves can write to their user document:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Helper function to check if a user is authenticated
    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    // Function to check if the userID from the request matches the authenticated UID
    function isUserAuthenticated(userID) {
      return isAuthenticated() && userID == request.auth.uid;
    }

    // Rules for the `users` collection
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow create: if isUserAuthenticated(uid);
    }
  }
}
```

In my research, I've come across several sources that suggest schema validation and request time checks are essential for security. Is this because, without these validations, it's possible to write values to the database using user authentication credentials through means other than the app, such as the CLI?

I'm looking for specific examples or explanations of how an attacker could exploit the lack of such validations. Any insights or advice on improving the security of these rules would be greatly appreciated

I haven't done anything yet

Answer (score 0):

In your current security rules you allow the user to only write data in their own document, but you're not checking anything about the data they write.

A malicious user can take the configuration data of your project from the app, and write their own code to do something completely different. They could write a (small) image exchange in that way, or a voicemail service, or anything else they can dream up, and you'd be paying the Firestore cost for that.

To prevent this, you'll want to expand your security rules to also only allow the data structures for your use-case. For an introduction on this, I recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [data validation ins security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/data-validation). If the database only allows storing data that matches with your use-case, it's much harder (and this less appealing) to abuse your database for other use-cases.

I also recommend looking into [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), as that is another way to make it harder for malicious users to run *their* code against *your* database.